# Laravel smtp configuration issue

Tags: php, laravel, email, gmail

Good morning friends. I'm using webmail to send Emails from my Laravel application. The problems is, email are recieved in Yahoo and mailtrap, but gmail doen't get emails.

Comment: Did you check the spam folder?

Comment: Yes, I did. The problem is it doesn't show any errors. If it shows me an error, I might know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, it's the regular behavior that you do not see the mail you application sent, in you Gmail-Outbox.

Besides, does the email get sent at all? Meaning, you receive no error. Is a mail being sent?

If not, check this:

- To use Gmail for sending mails, you have to allow "less secure apps".
- Check the configuration: For me, port 587 with tls works.

Comment: Thank you. I can send email to yahoo and mailtrap with the same configuration. I'm not using gmail to send Emails.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is gmail turned off less secure app,

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

so now its a challenge to send email through gmail smtp, you have to use service something like mailgun, or sendgrid or webmail.

Comment: I do use webmail to send Email. The problem is, my application send Email to yahoo, webmail or mailtrap, but not to Gmail.

Comment: These docs might help
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596#zippy=%2Crecipient-server-did-not-accept-our-requests

https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730